# Java Scanner Lookahead

Tags: java

Is there any way to implement Scanner.hasNextInt() so that it can check not only the i+1 token but the i+2 token? I am looking for a way to check if both inputs are numbers without printing the same error message twice.

Input should be in the form

> > 1 2

and I am trying to alert the user if input is of the form

> > 1 a, a 1, a a, aa aa, 1a 1, etc...

**What I wish it would look like: (does not work this way)**

```
            int pile1, pile2;

        // the second call to reader.hasNextInt() would be verifying pile2 to be int
        if (reader.hasNextInt() && reader.hasNextInt())
        {
            pile1 = reader.nextInt();
            pile2 = reader.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Your input is malformed. Try again");
        }
```

**What I currently have:**

```
                int pile1, pile2;
                if (reader.hasNextInt())
                    pile1 = reader.nextInt();
                else
                {
                   System.out.println("Your input is malformed. Try again");
                    return;
                }

                if (reader.hasNextInt())
                    pile2 = reader.nextInt();
                else
                {
                   System.out.println("Your input is malformed. Try again");
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

> **hasNext(String pattern)**  this method returns true if the next token matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println("input count of numbers to inputed:\t");
    int limit = 0;
    if (reader.hasNext("\\d+")) {
        reader.nextInt();
    } else {
        System.out.println("wrong input");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("please input data:\t");

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

        if (reader.hasNext("\\d+")) {
            data.add(reader.nextInt());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Your input is malformed. Try again");
            break;
        }
    }

    reader.close();

}
```

assumption:Since you need to stop scanning ,one must have predefined limit set or special exit condition from loop.